# WCF service with class inheritance

Tags: wcf, inheritance, enums

I've a WCF service which uses a class hierarchy. The base class, BaseService, has only basic information (go figure) and my inherited class has extended information. One of the properties of Service is a enum. BaseService has the DataContract attribute set with the KnownType attribute pointing to Service.

One of the services return a list of BaseService, but when I call it I get an error from WCF. I've enabled the log and can see that the error is related to the enum in Service not being set. The service is not returning a list of Service, but a list of BaseService, so the enum should not be relevant in the context. It seems that WCF is trying to return a list of Service, even though the method returns a list of BaseService.

The error message is:
There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:GetShallowServiceResult. The InnerException message was 'Enum value '0' is invalid for type 'MyService.ServiceTypeEnum' and cannot be serialized.

I can't figure out why this is happening?

**UPDATE:**
It turned out that I had missed changing a constructor to using the BaseService class instead of the inherited Service class. That ment that the WebService was trying to serialize some enum which wasn't set. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

How have you declared your enum? Have you used the following pattern?

```
public enum MyEnumeration
{
   [EnumMember]
   Value0 = 0,

   [EnumMember]
   Value1 = 1,

   [EnumMember]
   Value2 = 2
}
```

The [DataContract] attribute is not necessary on enums, BTW.

Comment: Yes - my enum is defined like that. I tried to add a value for 0 because of the error message, but I still get the same error message. It seems to me that the problem is with the class inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all included enums which will get serialized in the ServiceKnownType declaration.

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyEnum))]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ServiceMethod(MyEnum enom);
}
```